# Automorphism Group on Brauer-Severi variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X be a Brauer-Severi variety over k, i.e. a variety that becomes isomorphic to the projective space after base change to a Galois-field extension of k.

Does the automorphism group Aut(X) act on X transitivelly?

Is there any literature about the action of Aut(X) on X?

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to know if the automorphism group scheme $G$ of $X$ acts transitively in the sense that the multiplication morphism `$(m,\text{pr}_2):G\times_k X \to X\times_k X$` is a surjective morphism of schemes?  Or are you asking whether the induced map of sets of $k$-points is surjective, $G(k)\times X(k) \to X(k)\times X(k)$?  Of course the answer to both questions is yes, but the second question is a bit silly since $X(k)$ is nonempty if and only if $X$ is isomorphic to `$\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_k$`.  

Comment: I was thinking on something in the sense of transitivity on the closed points of X. So we can consider a finite non split field extension of k, say L, and ask for the transitivity of Aut(X(L))-action on X(L).


Comment: concretely: you have a closed point x in X and a closed point y in X, so is there an automorphism of X such that the automorphism maps x to y?

Comment: Peter: Well, at least the residue fields need to be isomorphic as $k$-algebras, or there is certainly no such automorphism.  Maybe a safer, more general question is to ask for a description of the orbits of Aut(X) on the closed points of X.  

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I recommend reading Section III.1 of Serre's "Galois Cohomology", particularly III.1.3 on pp. 123-124.  In that terminology, the key issue is whether or not the automorphism functor, $\text{Aut}_{X/k}$ in Serre's notation, is representable by a finite type $k$-scheme $G$.  Assuming that it is, then the base change of the morphism $(m,\text{pr}_2):G\times_k X\to X\times_k X$ to a field extension $L/k$ is the analogous morphism for the base change $L$-scheme, $X_L = X\times_{\text{Spec} k} \text{Spec} L$.  For some (finite) Galois extension $L/k$, there is an isomorphism $X_L \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_L$.  For this $L$-scheme, the multiplication morphism $(m,\text{pr}_2)$ is a surjective morphism of finite type $L$-schemes.  Since surjectivity can be checked after a faithfully flat base change, this implies that the original morphism $(m,\text{pr}_2)$ over $k$ is surjective.  Finally, since this is a morphism of finite type $k$-scheme, every surjective morphism is automatically surjective on closed points: the fiber over every closed point is a nonempty closed subscheme of the domain, which is finite type, hence the closed subscheme contains a closed point of the domain.

Therefore, the main issue is representability of $\text{Aut}_{X/k}$.  This is dealt with in many places.  The key here is that the dualizing sheaf $\omega_{X/k}$ is anti-ample, i.e., $\omega_{X/k}^\vee$ is ample.  The functor $\text{Aut}_{X/k}$ is very close to the functor $\text{Aut}_{X/k,\omega_{X/k}^\vee}$ "parameterizing" a $k$-automorphism $f$ together with an isomorphism between $\omega_{X/k}^\vee$ and $f^*\omega_{X/k}^\vee$.  This functor is itself a closed subfunctor of the linear $k$-group of $k$-linear automorphisms of $H^0(X,\omega_{X/k}^\vee)$.  There is a discussion of all of this in Section 2.1 of my article with de Jong, "Almost Proper GIT-Stacks and Discriminant Avoidance".

Comment: Regarding representability, couldn't one argue as follows? The base change of $Aut_{X/k}$ to $L$ is $Aut_{X_L/L} \simeq PGL^n_L$, so representability follows from flat descent for affine schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I am wrong but would this imply that for two closed points x and y in X with isomorphic residue fields there is an automorphism of X ( or an elemet in Aut_{X/k}(k) ) mapping x to y?